# Problems deleting records from table

Tags: php

Building a newbie level user management system. The following code is for the deleting of records from my table.

When you click on the delete link on the user management page, it forwards on through the delete file(this code)using the ID.

Can someone point out why it's not working and why $result is returning false? go easy on me I'm a complete novice :)

```
<?php

$host = 'localhost';
$user = 'tim_williams';
$pass = 'baroness';
$db  = 'php_db05';

$link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db);


if(!$link) {
  die("Database connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$id  = $_GET['id'];


$sql = "DELETE *
              FROM registeredusers
              WHERE UserID = $id";

$delete = mysqli_query($link, $sql);

//var_dump($delete);



if($delete) {
   header('Location: mysql-project-users-manage.php');
  exit;
}
```

?>

Comment: Your code is vunerable to SQL injection. At least, use `$id  = (int)$_GET['id'];` to prevent some. Also, try to run the `DELETE` statement directly in your database and check if you have any error message.

Comment: RTM on DELETE http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/delete.html yours is invalid and checking for errors would have thrown you something about it.

Answer (score 0):

You have an SQL syntax error, and since you never checked if the query succeeded, you never get told. At BARE MINIMUM, you should have something like

```
$result = mysqli_query(...) or die(mysqli_error($link));
```

Specifically:

```
$sql = "DELETE *
              FROM registeredusers
```

You don't specify fields in a `delete` query. You're deleting the entire row, so specifying fields (including `*` for all fields) is redundant/pointless. The syntax is simply:

```
 DELETE FROM yourtable
```

And on top of that, you're vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com), so enjoy having your server pwn3d.